# Swap every Nth element of two lists

Tags: python, list, swap

I have two lists as:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I need to swap every `N`th element of these lists. For example if `N=3`, desired result is:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 'c', 4, 5, 'f']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 3, 'd', 'e', 6]
```

I can do it via `for` loop and swap every `N`th element as:

```
>>> for i in range(2,len(l1),3):
...     l1[i], l2[i] = l2[i], l1[i]
... 
>>> l1, l2
([1, 2, 'c', 4, 5, 'f'], ['a', 'b', 3, 'd', 'e', 6])
```

I want to know whether there is much more efficient way to achieve it. May be without `for` loop.

Note: Length of both lists will be same.

Comment: I just got the idea of doing it via. `list slicing` and I think that is pretty efficient. Still I am interested to know if there is any better way. Not deleting the question as it may be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve that via `list slicing` as:

```
>>> l1[2::3], l2[2::3] = l2[2::3], l1[2::3]
>>> l1, l2
([1, 2, 'c', 4, 5, 'f'], ['a', 'b', 3, 'd', 'e', 6])
```